# text-align: center; при position: fixed;

Tags: html, css

Не выравнивает по центру текст "test". align="center" тоже не помогло.

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0">
 <div style="text-align: center">
  test
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где задана ширина блоков???

У тебя выравнивает по центру, вот только центр - блока, а блок небольшой ширины, поэтому текст прижат к краю. Сделай у первого блока ширину 100% - уже результат увидишь.

И вообще - пользуйся средствами разработчика, в Хроме, например - по F12 - проще будет.

Comment: Ну либо во время разработки ставь `border: 1px solid black` - визуально чтобы наблюдать. Но тогда возможны баги из-за наличия бордера.

Т.е. при установке свойств надо будет не забывать про этот бордер